# Adding limit's to nested value in graphql

Tags: graphql, limit

Here's a simple graphQL query to fetch all people. I'd like to add a limit to to the number of friends each (Person) node will have (say e.g. max 5) when retrieved. Is this possible in graphQL? I know its possible to add a limit to allPeople, something like `allPeople(limit: 5)`
but i don't think that will help my use-case.

```
{
  allPeople {
    nodes {
      id
      friends {
        name
        id
        phone
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @xadm could you answer the question, so i can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add params to `friends` 'level' in query

... if supported **and resolved separately** ...

... **there is no filtering or searching syntax defined in general graphql specs**.

It all depends on specific server/env, how resolved etc.

... probably it's better to resolve both levels (`people`+`friends`) in people resolver (one sql query) - in this case both filters/limits should be defined on 'parent' level - `allPeople(limit:5, friendsLimit:5)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm actually using GatsbyJS. I probably need to look into how to createResolvers for the same (or create a separate question).

Comment: gatsby has limited graphql functionality ...IMHO not worth the effort ...  return all data, limit in component - just render xx items (xx can be passed as param by context)

Comment: Makes sense. Although, just for knowledge sake, would be curious to know how it can be done.

Comment: use real/live graphql server for that ... it can be used later as source for gatsby